# 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' thrown

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Companyregister";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company_name", txtname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Register_no", txtreg_no.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", DropDownList1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtadrs.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtemail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact_no", txtphone.Text);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Response.Write("Register succesful");
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].Companyregister
    @Company_name varchar(50),
    @Register_no varchar(50),
    @Type varchar(50),
    @Address varchar(50),
    @Email varchar(50),
    @Contact_no varchar(50)
AS
    insert into company_reg (Company_name, Register_no, Type, Address, Email, Contact_no) 
    values (@Company_name, @Register_no, @Type, @Address, @Email, @Contact_no)

    RETURN 0
```

Error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: Make sure your stored procedure parameters match the data sizes in the table.  You're passing in a string that's too long for the field.

Comment: Have you tested your stored procedure separately (using management studio e.g.)?

Comment: have you check any one textbox value more than database size value or storeprocedure data size value

Comment: So, either one of the parameters / textbox values you pass to the stored procedure exceeds the specified size for that parameter. Which one that is, you have to find out yourself - using a debugger for example. What exactly is the question? How do you want to deal with that (prevent it by truncation, enlarging your parameter/column sizes, limit user input in the UI, etc.)? Merely stating a fact doesn't make a pretty good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following error indicates that one or more of your data field is NOT able to fit in the DB field. For eg, may be your address is of 60 characters but your DB size for it is only 50 characters.

> String or binary data would be truncated.

To solve this, first check if the data you are inserting complies to the sizes defined in you DB. To catch this more easily, define your parameters to stored procedure as follows:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Company_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtname.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Register_no", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtreg_no.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DropDownList1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtadrs.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtemail.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Contact_no", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtphone.Text;
```

Comment: Ideally we should have checks in place in UI layer itself before passing a field value to database. We should show error messages to the user instead if maximum allowed field width is being exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to start investigating exceptions is to wrap your code in `try/catch` blocks. This will allow you to dig down in the Exception and hopefully get a more meaningful description of the error. Submitting the Exception as part of your question will help the community in finding the cause.

Use a `try/catch` block as follows

```
try{
    // code goes here
}
catch (Exception e) // this block is only entered when an exception is thrown in the try block
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); // print the exception description to the Console (if console application)
}
```

As suggested in the comments, try executing the Stored Procedure using the same parameters and see if it's successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;     /// this is optional if you declare @ID in your store procedure 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Company_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtname.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Register_no", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value= txtreg_no.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtadrs.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtemail.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Contact_no", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtphone.Text;
```

And check your variable size and name